# OOP Airline Reservation

Tags: java, oop

I am creating a OOP on an airline reservation system. The air plane will have first class (2 rows, 4 seats per row (Seats are A B C D)), and an economy class (20 rows, 6 seats per row (Seats are A B C D E F). The row is separated by an aisle.

A user will input his name, class specification, and seat preference ([W]indow, [A]isle, [C]enter), and it will find the first available seat to put the user in.

EX.

Name: John Smith
Class: Economy
Seat Preference: [C]enter

Result:

Row 3 Seat B Name John Smith

My question is how I can create the first and economy constructors with the appropriate seating arrangements? Would I use an arraylist? or a 2-dimensional array with seats and seats per row? Or something else entirely?

Thank you!

Comment: It comes down to needs, personally, I would use a List (of List if needed), as it's much easier to manage. I might be tempted to create a Row class which described the number of seats per row and add these to a List. You could have (technically) 3 Lists, left, center, right columns for example

Comment: Not really an OO question. All yuo need is an array of seats!

Comment: @JamesAnderson All you *really* need is `4*2 + 6*20` bits.

Answer (score 1):

Start with class Seat, with properties Location: Window, Center, Aisle and position 'A', 'B',...

```
public enum Location { WINDOW, CENTER, AISLE }
public class Seat {
    private Location loc;
    private char pos;  // A, B, C...
    public Seat( Location loc, char pos ){...}
    //...
}
```

Create class Row, subclass into Business and Economy: the constructor is responsible for creating the appropriate seats. Seats may be in a List, and add number as a property of the Row.

```
public abstract class Row {
    private int number;
    private List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
    protected Row( int number ){ ... }
    public void addSeat( Seat seat ){...}
    public Seat findSeat( Location loc ){...}
}

public class Business extends Row {
    public Business( int number ){
        super( number );
        addSeat( Location.WINDOW, 'A' ); // continue as required
    }
}
public class Economy extends Row {
    public Economy( int number ){
        super( number );
        addSeat( Location.WINDOW, 'A' ); 
        addSeat( Location.CENTER, 'B' ); // continue as required
    }
}
```

Create class Plane that fills its `List<Row>` using Business and Economy, setting row numbers (make sure to omit row *number* 13).

```
public class Plane {
    private static final NUM_BUSINESS = 2;
    private static final NUM_ECONOMY = 20;
    private List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    public Plane(){
        int iRow = 1;
        for( int i = 0; i < NUM_BUSINESS; ++i ){
            rows.add( new Business( iRow++ ) );
        }
        // similar for Economy
    }
    public Seat findSeat( boolean business, Location loc ){
        // ...
    }
}
```